# Designing Experiments

Tags: co.combinatorics

I have a question regarding designing experiments that i can't quite wrap my head around. The question will be posted as an image below!

[image: Image of the question]

So the question gives us three factors with a specified amount of levels corresponding to each of these factors. One of the levels is a default level.

So I would write:

Request rate : 9 = 8 + 1 (default)
Job size : 8 = 7 + 1 (default)
Processor speed : 7 = 6 + 1 (default)

But when doing the calculations for b) I get a bit confused. What does "default scenario as a baseline" mean in that context?

For a) - I would interpret this as:
We have the default scenario which is 1 combination. Then if we "lock" the job size at a specific value and the processor speed at a specific value we get 8 possible combinations for request rate. If we do the same procedure with the other factors we would get:

8 + 7 + 6 = **21** combinations. But we have to add the default scenario. So we would get **22** combinations. This seems to be the correct answer for a)

But for b), the default scenario is not 1 according to numerous sources. I understand that we take two factors at a time and fix the third. So this would give us (excluding default levels):

8 * 7 * 1 + 8 * 6 * 1 + 6 * 7 * 1 = **146** combinations. But somehow (according to some answers), we have to add the result in a) to this. Why?

I believe that I am missing something here. What does "default scenario as baseline" mean when doing experiments?